# HttpServletRequest getting new session

Tags: session, servlets, servlet-filters

I have an application that does authentication via oauth.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    // Check if already logged in
    if (getUser(httpReq) != null) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    // Try to parse auth response
    if (procAuthResponse(httpReq)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    // Go to auth server
    sendAuthRequest(httpReq, httpResp);
}
```

This works fine.
In the method procAuthResponse I am paring the response from the server and to this.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute(USER_PRINCIPLE_ATR, userInfo);
```

It works also well, but there is a session scoped class with the method getCurrent user, that is used by servlets.

```
    public UserInfo getCurrentUser() {

        HttpSession session = getHttpSession();

        if (session == null) {
            LOG.warn("Method getCurrentUser: unable to find a session");
            return null;
        }

        Object user = session.getAttribute(OAuthLoginFilter.USER_PRINCIPLE_ATR);
        if (!(user instanceof UserInfo)) {
            LOG.warn(String.format("Method getCurrentUser, wrong type for attribute %s", OAuthLoginFilter.USER_PRINCIPLE_ATR));
            return null;
        }

        currentUser = (UserInfo) user;

        return currentUser;
    }
```

This method gets called multiple times and it turnes out that on the first call everything works as expected and after that the getHttpSession() returns a different session that does not contain any information that is set in the filter class. It is not a new session every time, the session without the needed information is always the same.

Code of getHttpSession()

```
private HttpSession getHttpSession() {
    Object request = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        LOG.warn("not a valid http request");
        return null;
    }
    HttpServletRequest hreq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    return hreq.getSession(false);
}
```

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Thx for your help

Comment: There is nothing really JSF related in this question. Yes you use the FacesContext, but if 'request' is not null it has done its work!

Comment: Is 'hreq.getSession(false)' not part of JSF?

Comment: Nope... as you can **see** it is from the `HttpServletRequest`. Nothing JSF related. And **effectively** your question is about getting a new session each time... Not aout the missing attributes. Search for that on the internet

Comment: Ok I will update the question an do some more reseach. And it is actually not a new session each time it is just one new session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was still an old filter class, not configured in the web.xml, but annotated with `@WebFilter("/*")`.
I deleted this file and now everything works as expected.